# Problems with "while" bash

Tags: bash, while-loop

I need to control files in a folder... The script has to wait the file until it exists...

These files have the name... The format is `file_d01_YYYY-MM-DD_HH:00:00`. For example:

```
file_d01_2018-11-12_00:00:00
file_d01_2018-11-12_01:00:00
```

And so on, for 7 days ahead.

```
!/bin/bash


ZZ=`date +%k`
date=$(date +%Y%m%d)
if [[ $ZZ -ge 2 ]] && [[ $ZZ -lt 14 ]] ; then  #03:45 UTC
ZZ=00
PARAM=`date +%Y%m%d`$ZZ
PARAM2=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
elif [[ $ZZ -ge 14 ]] && [[ $ZZ -lt 23 ]] ; then #15:45 UTC
ZZ=12
PARAM=`date +%Y%m%d`$ZZ
PARAM2=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
fi


rundir=/home/$PARAM/wrfv3
dir=/home/$PARAM

data=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
data1=$(date -d "1 day" +%Y-%m-%d)
data2=$(date -d "2 day" +%Y-%m-%d)
data3=$(date -d "3 day" +%Y-%m-%d)
data4=$(date -d "4 day" +%Y-%m-%d)
data5=$(date -d "5 day" +%Y-%m-%d)
data6=$(date -d "6 day" +%Y-%m-%d)




days=( "$data" "$data1" "$data2" "$data3" "$data4" "$data5" "$data6" )   #array of days
values=( {00..23} ) #array of 24 hours
echo ${#values[@]}

# Here, using to loops, I check if files exist...for every day and hour
for day in "${days[@]}"; do
for value in "${values[@]}"; do
echo file_d01_${day}_${value}:00:00

while [ ! -f $rundir/file_d01_2018-11-15_20:00:00  ] # while file doesn't exist...wait...and repeat checking till it exists...
do
echo "waiting for the file"
sleep 10
done
echo "file exists"
sleep 5

done
done
```

I receive always "waiting for the file"...and they exist... where is the problema in the code?

Comment: Are you really sure the file exists?  Perhaps use `set -x` to see the expanded version of the path at that point.  (Also, consider using https://www.shellcheck.net/ to find a lot of gotchas.)

Comment: A good Stack Overflow question containing code has that code presented as a [mcve] -- the *shortest possible* code that anyone else can run themselves to see the same problem, with everything unrelated to that problem removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the double quotes `""` to protect the path. It's a good practice. Also bash expansion escapes the `:` character, so maybe it is an issue in your context (not in the one i did the test).

```
while [ ! -e "$rundir/file_d01_2018-11-15_20:00:00" ]
```

I would suggest to follow those steps:

1. Protect the path with **double** quotes `""` (not simple ones, otherwise `$rundir` won't be expanded)
2. Write `echo "waiting for the file $rundir/file_d01_2018-11-15_20:00:00"` to see what path you're testing
3. Additionally, use `-e` to see any changes (`-e` checks for a path existence, not only a regular file one)

Note: the brackets `[ ]` invokes in fact `test`. So, `man test` will give you the operators you can use and their meanings. Also nowadays `bash` has double brackets `[[ ]]` as built-in operators, more powerful, which can be used instead.

Comment: `-f` will test if it exists and is a regular file, so a directory would not pass `-f` but would pass `-e` for example

Comment: This is a misleading answer. There is nothing in the question that indicates that the use of `-f` instead of `-e` might be an issue here. It sounds more like a quoting issue, and while you did mention that in your edit, the answer still reads as "you need to use `-e` instead of `-f`".

Comment: Much better. Have an upvote. I would caution against making a habit of using `-e` when you are actually testing for the existence of a regular file. The more your code aligns with what you're expecting to be happening, the less chance there is that something will go haywire. For this reason, any time I am working with regular files, I use `-f` so that there is no doubt. In the past, I've written scripts that obliterated whole directories of important data, because of little details like that leading to unexpected consequences. Bottom line, if you mean files, your code should use `-f`.

Comment: Good point @MikeHolt, indeed. Thanks for the notice and your pretty cool behaviour.

Comment: Thanks you also @EricRenouf.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question contains:

```
echo file_d01_${day}_${value}:00:00
while [ ! -f $rundir/file_d01_2018-11-15_20:00:00  ]
```

It's calculating a file name, echoing it, and then checking for a (probably different) fixed, unchanging, file name.  It should check for the calculated file name.  For example:

```
file=file_d01_${day}_${value}:00:00
echo "$file"
while [ ! -f "$rundir/$file"  ]
```

To make debugging easier, it would be better to have:

```
filepath=$rundir/file_d01_${day}_${value}:00:00
echo "$filepath"
while [ ! -f "$filepath"  ]
```

The full code in the question has many issues (starting with a broken shebang line).  It's a good idea to make Bash code [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean.

Comment: Insofar as the code has a wider array of problems than can be reasonably answered, that's a reason *not to answer it* but instead to vote for closure -- see the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section in [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly the bullet points regarding questions which "require too much guidance for you to answer in full", and the inclusion by reference of [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), which itself references [mcve] rules.